# Android studio layout become blank when i enter text into multiline text

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[Image 1-Before entering text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0lSj.jpg)

In this edit text view i if i enter a single word it becomes like this

[Image 2-after entering text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okMkb.jpg)

XMl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollbarSize="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:text="OK"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have added whole XMl file
I want to enter the text into my text field but i am not able to do it,i have tried my of the solutions before but still this issue is the same

Comment: could you add your layout.xml instead of a photo please?

Comment: please add layout.xml file

Comment: add layout.xml file

Comment: Added XML images

Comment: please refrain from using images instead of actual code, you can very easily copy and paste your code here

Comment: You have a simple error in the code, just copy and paste your XML code here and you will get help

Comment: xml file is updated

Comment: how are you entering the text in the text field? from the layout file or programmatically from your activity/fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your EditText doesn't have an id name and you're missing the "d" in the unit "dp" of the width attribute. Also when you constrain it you mustn't include the + symbol in the id name of the other view. + is used for new views, not for referencing existing views. Make these changes and you should be fine!

**Edit:** If you add your xml code, I can pinpoint the specific changes, but I can't do that if you're only sharing the images

**Edit 2:** 
When you're using Left-to-Right layouts it's redundant to have margin left and margin start, or margin right and margin end, as they're the same thing. I wasn't breaking you're layout but I removed that. Also, I wrapped the height to the contents of your textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollbarSize="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:text="OK"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It doesn't fail for me now. If it still does for you, chances are you're giving the same names to textviews of other layouts (each view should have a unique name, as everything is stored in the same R file).

Comment: can i contact you in mail or other place i am new at this community and having problem uploading my code

Comment: @kathanpatel open your xml file and select all the code and copy it (Control+A for windows  or Cmd+A for mac, then Control + C for windows or Cmd+C for mac). Then you come here and edit your post by pasting the copied text (Control + V for windows or Cmd + V for mac) . Then you select all the code that you copied and do a Control+K for windows or Cmd+K for mac, to format it as code and post it. Even if that fails, copy paste the entire thing, and I'll format it accordingly

Comment: thanks i was able to post my XML and now you can see that